# XGBoost Regressor normalize target

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, xgboost

Is it a good idea to scale/standarized (log-transform/normalize) your target variable in an XGBoost regressor model? Like in a linear model.

Or should we expect that XGBoost will fin the optimal split points even if your distribution is skewed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XGBoost is a tree based model and tree models really do not depend on scaling. But there are some cases where normalizing provides better accuracy.